# linq 2 left joins

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

So I wanted to make a linq query out of my left join sql (refer to it below). I just don't know how to properly position the ".TournamentId = 1" condition on the joins. Currently when running this on my database I get the results that I want. which is a couple of rows from the Type table with null fields.

```
select typ.Id, stat.PromoterId, temp.PromoterId
from ReportTypes type
left join ReportTemplateStatus status on status.PromoterId = type.TypeId and status.TournamentId = 1
left join ReportTemplates temp on temp.ClientId = status.PromoterId and temp.TournamentId = 1

Promoter
 - promoterId
 - promoterName

Tournament
 - tournamentId
 - tournamentName

ReportType
 - TypeId

ReportTemplateStatus 
 - promoterId (this is the key)
 - tournamentId
 - typeId

ReportTemplates
 - promoterId
 - tournamentId
```

This is currently what I have:

```
var report  =  from type in context.ReportTypes 
                 join status in context.ReportTemplateStatus on type.TypeId equals status.TypeId
                 join temp in context.ReportTemplates  on status.promoterId equals temp.promoterId into iReports
                 from reports in iReports.Where (rep => rep.promoterId == _promoterId && rep.tournamentId == _tournamentId).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { my fields});
```

but it's giving me a null.

any ideas on how the linq should work? maybe separate into "itables" (iReports) or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you what you are looking for

```
var report  =  from type in context.ReportTypes 
               from status in context.ReportTemplateStatus.Where(x => type.TypeId == x.TypeId)        
                                                          .Where(x => x.TournamentId == 1)  
                                                          .DefaultIfEmpty()
               from reports in context.ReportTemplates.Where(x => status.promoterId == x.promoterId)
                                                      .Where(x => x.TournamentId == 1)
                                                      .DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new { my fields};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
  var query = from person in people
                    join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj
                    from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new { person.FirstName, PetName = (subpet == null ? String.Empty : subpet.Name) };
```

Thanks